# email header format (PHP)

Tags: php, email, header, mime

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong on this? I'm adding an attachment to an email from a blob in the database. I'm assuming the headers on this are incorrectly formatted but have spent all day on this and still cant get it to work!

```
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
$headers2 = array(
'From: ' . $fromName . ' < ' . $fromEmail . ' > ', 
'BCC: will.evans.1972@gmail.com',
'MIME-Version: 1.0',
'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;',
'boundary='.$mime_boundary, 
);
// multipart boundary 
$body = '--'.$mime_boundary.'\n' ;
$body .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n';
$body .= $message ; 
$body .= '--'.$mime_boundary.'\n';

// preparing attachments
  global $wpdb;
  $data = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT documentblob FROM quote");
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

    $fname1='quotation.pdf';

$body .= 'Content-Type: {"application/octet-stream"};\n';
$body .= 'name="'.$fname1.'"\n'. 
$body .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment;\n';
$body .= 'filename="'.$fname1.'"\n';
$body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n'; 
$body .= $data . '\n\n';
$body .= '--'.$mime_boundary.'\n';

wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers2);
```

Comment: Hand-rolling your emails is probably a huge mistake. Try and use a library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) at the absolute least.

Comment: Here to second the use of PHPMailer and to advise you NOT to hand-bomb your own headers.

Comment: Thats just not possible in this scenario, I am restricted to using wp_mail (Wordpress mailer) and that does not have the ability to add a blob as an attachment. It CAN do attachments....but I don't have the rights on the platform to turn the blob into a file before attaching.

Answer (score 0):

You should close the last boundary with two more hypes, so your last body line should be the following:

```
$body .= '--'.$mime_boundary.'--\n';
```